# Spring MVC web application: No default constructor found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Project ZIP: http://goo.gl/ddhLg5

---

Spring web app cannot be executed giving HTTP Status 500 error. It also writes out that No default constructor found for DSLR but in fact there is a default constructor. Maybe it has to do with application context or the way my beans declared? What is the reason my application cannot start?

**DSLR:**

```
 package main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model;

    public class DSLR {

    public DSLR() {
    }
    public void init() {}

    private int dslrId;
    private String model;
    private int price;
    private String description;

    public int getDslrId() {
        return dslrId;
    }

    public void setDslrId(int dslrId) {
        this.dslrId = dslrId;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DSLR [dslr=" + dslrId + ", model=" + model
                + ", price=" + price+ ", description=" + description+"]";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
                   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**DSLRServletController-servlet.xml:**

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.springapp.mvc" >
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean name="s" class="main.java.com.springapp.mvc.controller.DSLRServletController">
        <property  name="dslrDAO" ref="dslrDAO" />
        <property  name="DSLR" ref="DSLR" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dslrDAO" class="main.java.com.springapp.mvc.dao.DSLRDAO">

    </bean>
    <bean id="DSLR" class="main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR">

    </bean>


</beans>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**ERROR:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [[Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;.<init>()

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [[Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;.<init>()

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [[Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;.<init>()
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:927)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [[Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;.<init>()
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:770)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:363)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:439)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;.<init>()
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:770)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:363)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:439)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 logs.
```

---

**Main controller class:**

```
package main.java.com.springapp.mvc.controller;

import main.java.com.springapp.mvc.dao.DSLRDAO;
import main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;
import main.java.com.springapp.mvc.pckg.DSLRForm;
import main.java.com.springapp.mvc.pckg.DSLRValidaor;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

@Controller
public class DSLRServletController extends HttpServlet  {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DSLRServletController.class);

    private DSLR DSLR;
    private DSLRDAO dslrDAO;
    private DSLR dslr;

   /* request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
    List list = getActions(request, response);
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");*/

    //@Autowired   ???
    public DSLRServletController() {
        this.dslrDAO = new DSLRDAO();
    }

    public void init() {logger.error("DSLRServlet.init(): just started"); }
    /*
            /s                                    GET
            /s?id=1                               GET
            /s?action=save                        POST
            /dslrservice?id=1&tm=<timestamp>      GET
     */
@RequestMapping(value = "/s", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHTMLResponse(@ModelAttribute("dslrs") DSLR dslrs[],
                               @ModelAttribute("dslr") DSLR dslr,
                               @ModelAttribute("dslrErrors") HashMap dslrErrors,
                               @ModelAttribute ("dslrform") DSLRForm dslrForm,
                               @RequestParam("id") String paramId,
                               @RequestParam("action") String paramAction,
                               Model model){

    if(paramId == null || paramId.equals("")){
        //show_all_dslrs
        dslrs = getAllDslrs();    // DSLR adslrs[] -> to MODEL;
       return "dslrs";
    }else{
        //show_this_dslr;
        HashMap<String,Object> dslrHashMap = getDSLRById(paramId);
        dslr = (DSLR) dslrHashMap.get("dslr");
        dslrForm = (DSLRForm)dslrHashMap.get("dslrForm");
        dslrErrors = (HashMap)dslrHashMap.get("dslrErrors");

            if(dslr != null){
//                getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/dslr.jsp").forward(request, response);
                return "dslr";
            }

            else{
                return "error";
            }


    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/s", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showHTMLResponsePOST(@ModelAttribute("dslrs") DSLR dslrs[],
                               @ModelAttribute("dslrErrors") HashMap<?,?> dslrErrors,
                               @ModelAttribute ("dslrform") DSLRForm dslrForm,

                               @RequestParam("id") String paramId,
                               @RequestParam("action") String paramAction,
                               @RequestParam("dslr_model") String paramModel,
                               @RequestParam("price") String paramPrice,
                               @RequestParam("description") String paramDescription,
                               Model model){
    int iStatusCode = 0;
    if(paramAction.equals("save") )
        iStatusCode = saveDSLR(paramId, paramModel, paramPrice, paramDescription, dslrErrors, dslrForm);    // POST

    return "dslrs";

}

    private int saveDSLR(String paramId,
                         String paramModel,
                         String paramPrice,
                         String paramDescription,
                         HashMap<?,?> context_dslrErrors,
                         DSLRForm context_dslrForm
                         ) {
        int byte0 = 1;
        try {

            DSLRValidaor dslrValidaor = new DSLRValidaor();

            DSLRForm dslrForm = new DSLRForm();
            dslrForm.setDslrId(paramId);
            dslrForm.setModel(paramModel);
            dslrForm.setPrice(paramPrice);
            dslrForm.setDescription(paramDescription);

            HashMap hashmap = dslrValidaor.Validate(dslrForm);
            if(hashmap.size() > 0) {
                context_dslrForm = dslrForm;
                context_dslrErrors = hashmap;
                byte0 = -1;
            } else{
                DSLRDAO planedao = new DSLRDAO();
                DSLR dslr = new DSLR();
                dslr.setDslrId(Integer.parseInt(paramId));
                dslr.setModel(paramModel);
                dslr.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(paramPrice));
                dslr.setDescription(paramDescription);
                planedao.update(dslr);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            logger.error((new StringBuilder()).append("DSLRServlet.saveDSLR():").append(exception.getMessage()).toString());
            byte0 = -1;
        }
        return byte0;

    }

    private DSLR[] getAllDslrs(){
        DSLR adslrs[] = null;
        try
        {
            DSLRDAO DSLRDAO = new DSLRDAO();
            adslrs = (DSLR[])DSLRDAO.findAll();
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            logger.error((new StringBuilder()).append("PlaneServlet.getAllPlanes():").append(exception.getMessage()).toString());
        }
//        request.setAttribute("dslrs", adslrs);
        return adslrs;
    }

    private HashMap<String, Object> getDSLRById(String s)
    {
        HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        DSLR dslr = null;
        try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            DSLRDAO DSLRDAO = new DSLRDAO();
            dslr = (DSLR)DSLRDAO.findById(i);

            DSLRForm dslrForm = new DSLRForm();
            dslrForm.setDslrId(Integer.toString(dslr.getDslrId()));
            dslrForm.setModel(dslr.getModel());
            dslrForm.setPrice(Integer.toString(dslr.getPrice()));
            dslrForm.setDescription(dslr.getDescription());


            map.put("dslr", dslr);
            map.put("dslrform", dslrForm);
            map.put("dslrErrors", new HashMap());
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            logger.error((new StringBuilder()).append("DSLRServlet.getDSLRById():").append(exception.getMessage()).toString());
        }
        return map;
    }

    public void setDslrDAO(DSLRDAO dslrDAO) {
        this.dslrDAO = dslrDAO;
    }

    public DSLRDAO getDslrDAO() {
        return dslrDAO;
    }

    public void setDSLR(main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR DSLR) {
        dslr = DSLR;
    }

    public main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR getDSLR() {
        return dslr;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE1:**

**new mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.springapp.mvc" >
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**And @Autowired was put in DSLRServletController:**

```
@Autowired
    public DSLRServletController() {
        this.dslrDAO = new DSLRDAO();
    }
```

**Errors:**

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public main.java.com.springapp.mvc.controller.DSLRServletController()
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:976)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**For some reason 2 errors appeared. What should be changed to set up project correctly?**

---

**UPDATE3**

**the new mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.springapp.mvc" >
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="DSLR" class="main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR" />
</beans>
```

Apart from @Autowired added in  **UPDATE1**, another one is added (in **DSLRServletController**):

```
@Autowired
    public void setDSLR(DSLR DSLR) {
        dslr = DSLR;
    }
```

---

**UPDATE4:**

Back to the original errors : `Could not instantiate bean class [[Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;]`

I am confused. **What's wrong?**

Comment: How class `DSLR` implements `Serializable`?

Comment: I have no idea, most probably it doesn't.

Comment: It doesn't, and I can't see why it would/should.

Comment: Your build appears to be screwy. The `main.java` at the front makes it look like you have a Maven directory structure but are trying to build under Ant (or Eclipse without m2e), and that would cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: Java is not C! DSLR dslrs[] is c style.  Use Java style DSLR[] dslrs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside your controller method , you have used a parameter as array like below

```
@ModelAttribute("dslrs") DSLR dslrs[]
```

so use collection like list instead

```
@ModelAttribute("dslrs") ArrayList<DSLR> dslrs
```

Comment: After I made changes as you suggested, now I am having `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface`. What's wrong?

Comment: oh ok got it..make it arraylist instead of list

Answer (score 4):

This is the error message you would get if `DSLR` had no default constructor:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR.<init>()
```

Now compare this to your error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;.<init>()
```

Do you notice the difference? The `[L`? The error means that you cannot instantiate an array with a constructor, because an array has no constructor. That's why you can't use an array as a parameter for your controller method. At least not that way. Use a collection and you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

I note a little redundancy. It shouldn't, by itself, cause these problems, but it may be worth exploring:

You use `<context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.springapp.mvc" >`, which seems like it's intended to load your `@Controller`-annotated `DSLRServletController`. If that is the case, then there is no need to declare the bean named `s` in your XML configuration. You can simply put `@Autowired` on the bean property setters. Alternatively, you can remove the `<context:component-scan>` from your XML configuration, and trust your delcaration of the controller to be sufficient.

Additionally, though it's probably not related. If you load something using `@Controller` and classpath annotation scanning, you don't need to implement `HttpServlet` at all. The point of `@Controller` and Spring MVC is to make it so that your controllers can be Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs).

Most importantly, it looks like your `web.xml` is only causing `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` to be loaded (by using the servlet name as a hint), and nothing is loading `DSLRServletController-servlet.xml`. A consequence of this, is that your `<context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.springapp.mvc"/>` is causing the controller to be loaded, but none of it's properties are being set. To further clean up your system, move your `DSLRServletController-servlet.xml` into `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` so that your spring contexts are configured from a single config.

Comment: As you suggested I put together 2 XML configuration files into `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`. What exactly in that code are `the bean property setters` where `@Autowired` should be put? I removed `extends HttpServlet` and got 2  errors...

Comment: Would be helpful if I attached project's zip?

Comment: You're almost there! Regarding your update, you now have two `InternalResourceViewResolver`s defined. You can remove one of those. Second, `@Autowired` means that spring is supposed to look at the method, and then guess what bean should be injected there. With that in mind, you need `public void setDSLR` to be `@Autowired`. Once you do that, the next exception you'd get is that there is no candidate bean of type `DSLR` to inject. Why? Because there is no bean of `DSLR` defined in your current xml. You can fix this by introducing a `DSLR` bean in your xml like you initially had before.

Comment: For now, the `HttpServlet` stuff isn't really important. Nothing is sensitive to that class hierarchy. This 'servlet' exists within the Spring context as a java object that Spring MVC will reflect on in order to figure out how to make it jive. Once you are able to make a request that is mapped to that controller (and have it not die due to property injection problems), then we can worry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while running Spring boot application using Apache Tomcat 9.0.
    Now, I have resolved this.

1. I have commented two lines as below. (ie, whatever you have used here, just comment and run).then it will work.

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/userhome")
   public String userhome(Model model) {
       System.out.println("inside  bck...");
       //List<String> colorList = colorList();`enter code here`
       //model.addAttribute("theme", colorList);
       //model.addAttribute("home", new UserHome()); 
       return "userhomePage";
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was not that there is not default constructor. The issue was that there were no setters for fields of the json DTO that is passed to the controller in a rest post call.