# Could not instantiate bean class: BeanInstantiationException

Tags: java, spring

I cannot get rid of error:

```
  HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [[Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;]: 
No default constructor found; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;.<init>()
```

I actually have constructor in DSLR class. What's wrong with my code?

---

Code here > Spring MVC WebApp: http://goo.gl/ddhLg5

---

**DSLR class which is supposedly causing error:**

```
package main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    public class DSLR {


    public DSLR() {
    }


    private int dslrId;
    private String model;
    private int price;
    private String description;

    public int getDslrId() {
        return dslrId;
    }

    public void setDslrId(int dslrId) {
        this.dslrId = dslrId;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DSLR [dslr=" + dslrId + ", model=" + model
                + ", price=" + price+ ", description=" + description+"]";
    }
}
```

---

In DSLRServletController which instantiates DSLR I made changes:

**@ModelAttribute("dslrs") DSLR dslrs[]**

changed to:

**@ModelAttribute("dslrs") List dslrs**

which got rid of previous error and gave:

`org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface`

---

**SOLVED** here: [Spring MVC web application: No default constructor found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679564/spring-mvc-web-application-no-default-constructor-found/23685441?noredirect=1#comment36391704_23685441)
*If anyone can summarize and write the answer here I'd be happy to accept!*

Comment: change your package of `DSLR` from `main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model` to `com.springapp.mvc.model`

Comment: Why should I need to do that?

Comment: because `src/main/java` is the location where maven search for your classes to compile, any thing after that will be `actual package`

Comment: If I change `main.java.com.springapp.mvc.model` to `com.springapp.mvc.model` then I will have to move `DSLR` to other directory but I need to keep my java classes well organized. How it is connected to resolution of my error?

Comment: @SajanChandran that's not the problem at all...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for certain frameworks to initialize objects in such a way, you have to provide a **[default constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor)** (a constructor that takes no arguments), *even if it doesn't do anything*.

This is due to the fact you probably have another constructor in there that takes at least one argument. Logically, the library doesn't know what arguments to pass to every arbitrary class you pass it.

This is indicated in the error where it says `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lmain.java.com.springapp.mvc.model.DSLR;.<init>()`:

- `NoSuchMethodException` means it can't find a method it expects at runtime (through reflection)
- `.<init>()` refers to the constructor (constructors don't *technically* have names, since they're always just the name of the class itself; therefore, the JVM refers to them as `<init>()`).

Comment: I have default constructor: `public DSLR() {}`. And I don't have any other than this constructors in `DSLR` class.  Is it correct? If so then why Spring keep complaining?

Comment: @RCola Show us your code; show us the line that is throwing this exception

Comment: That is correct and it should work, but without seeing any code I can't say for sure.

Comment: There is no specific line, there is only a message saying Could not instantiate bean class `DSLR`

Answer (score 5):

As the error is impossible with the `DSLR` class you shared with us, my guess is that your server might contain an old class.

I suggest cleaning the project as well as the Tomcat installation from within your IDE.

- **Eclipse**:  Project -> Clean ...
- **Tomcat**: Right click on the server in Servers view -> Clean ...

Comment: Thank again, but you already solved this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679564/spring-mvc-web-application-no-default-constructor-found/23685441#23685441       ;)